# Smartface Codereader starts but do not read any code

Tags: smartface.io

I used the following sample code in order to test the CodeReader component :

```
  function Page1_TextButton1_OnPressed(e){


Pages.Page1.CodeReader1.visible = true;


 Pages.Page1.CodeReader1.readCode(SMF.UI.CodeType.linear,function()
{
  alert(Pages.Page1.CodeReader1.value);
},function()
{
  alert("There is an error");
});
```

When I press the button, the control displays the camera stream, but nothing ever happens afterwards : it does not reach neither the OnSuccess nor the OnFailure callback functions.

The camera does not focus either.

Is there any extra code I should add ? Should I explicitly call the phone camera ? How ?

Thanks,

nico

P.S. : I have tested on 2 different android phones

Comment: Are you trying to read a linear barcode? If so, the camera frame might be too small to read, can you try with a wider 'CodeReader' object?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the codeReader object is so small to read a barcode.

I suggest you to read the article below;

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/controls/codereader/

Comment: This was also my first guess, so I tried various sizes, up to full screen. No matter the size, and no matter the type of code (linear or QR), nothing happens... Is it working for you guys ? With the code of http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/controls/codereader/ ?

Comment: I tested with that codeLines;

var codeReader1 = new SMF.UI.CodeReader({
    top: "10%",
    left: "10%"
});
Pages.Page1.add(codeReader1 );
and I write on_Show event of Page;

Pages.Page1.CodeReader1.readCode("qr", function () {
    alert(Pages.Page1.CodeReader1.value)
}, function () {
    alert("Failure")
});
It reads and show me the value.

Comment: I used about the same code. I have tested again and it works on an iPhone(5S), but still nothing on Android...

Comment: did it work on android ? Please tell I am working on android for same?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1 - Drag in CodeReader into your Design Area.

2 - Write this code in the script for that page.

```
function MyPage_Self_OnShow(e){
Pages.MyPage.CodeReader1.readCode("[CODE TYPE (e.g. "qr")]",
    function(){
        alert("Pages.MyPage.CodeReader1.value");
    },
    function(){
       alert("fail"); 
    });
}
```

Try reading [the documentation](https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/controls/codereader/) if you have any other questions!